# Associative Array get key value in PHP

Tags: php, associative-array

```
array(24) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "9" ["facebook_id"]=> string(15) "381305418721463" ["first_name"]=> string(4) "John" ["last_name"]=> string(4) "Does" ["current_latitude"]=> string(10) "-37.825697" ["current_longitude"]=> string(10) "144.999965" ["current_address"]=> string(45) "229 Swan Street, Richmond VIC 3121, Australia" ["date_of_birth"]=> string(10) "01/01/1990" ["city"]=> string(30) "Melbourne, Victoria, Australia" ["country"]=> string(0) "" ["email_address"]=> string(22) "bzingatester@gmail.com" ["profile_pic"]=> string(0) "" ["first_login"]=> string(2) "no" ["blocked_users_id"]=> string(0) "" ["my_friend"]=> string(52) "10152805813948795,10155307822515151,1389504958030240" ["search_radius"]=> string(2) "50" ["device_type"]=> string(3) "ios" ["device_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["device_token"]=> string(64) "6ddaf9d59418e99b1c9cb28c21d94647bfed9f78a80b410164c1f2798beee84a" ["hideFromActivityFeed"]=> string(2) "no" ["hideFromFriendsofFriends"]=> string(2) "no" ["hideNotification"]=> string(2) "no" ["created_date"]=> string(19) "2015-01-07 01:00:11" ["modified_date"]=> string(19) "2015-02-27 05:36:12" }
```

In PHP I have an array called `$userData` as per above, I want to be able to echo values such as first name 'first_name',  using code like this

```
echo $userInfo->first_name;
```

(this doesnt seem to work)

I **DO NOT** want to loop and fetch all keys in array using foreach, just get values 'first_name', 'last_name' ect. from the array

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this,

```
$first_name =  $userInfo['first_name'] // $userInfo is array name
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :) However does not seem to work. The page throws errors... Btw its running on Laravel, the php side code is 
`code`
$user = DB::table('users')->where('user_id', '=', $i)->first();
     
$userInfo =  (array) $user;
     
$first_name =  $userInfo['first_name'] // $userInfo is array name
   
var_dump($userInfo);`code`

Comment: Laravel error "Whoops, there was an error." If I take out that code you sent me the page still loads.

Comment: THanks for the help. FYI This statement runs correctly I can get all the values, but not individually which is what I want `foreach($userInfo as $x => $x_value) {
        echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
        echo "<br>";
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Actually we use `arrays` in programming to prevent loop or something like this to find a value, so instead of this structure,

```
$a = 'text1';
$b = 0;
$c = true;
$d = 'text2';
```

we use arrays:

```
$array = array('a' = > 'text1', 'b' => 0, 'c' => true, 'd' => 'text2' );
```

and to access the value of some key, we call the key name, inside brackets after array's name:

```
echo $array['a'];
//will echo text1
//or
echo $array['b'];
//will echo true
```

This is `associative array`...

if you just pass values to an array without keys, php will use numeric keys instead...

```
$array = array( 'text1', '0', true, 'text2' );

$array[0] = 'text1';
$array[1] = 0;
$array[2] = true;
$array[3] = 'text2';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the array to object and then use -> like below

```
  $userData= (object) $userData;
```

And then
      $userData->firstName ..etc

Comment: Thanks now I have a new error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` highlighting the line above.

Comment: i think you mess up your code, can you show me it ?? you can't use (object) $userData then $userData['firstName'] because its not an array anymore     
are you sure you made $userData = (object) $userData; before using $userData->firstName ?

Comment: if you can show me the whole area code not just array contents so i could figure the error out

Comment: `code`
  <body class="home">
 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">                
   
    <h1 class="pageTitle">Users</h1>  
    
    <?php
  echo "<ul class='tableRow'>";
     
   for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

     
     $userData = DB::table('users')->where('user_id', '=', $i)->first();
  

      $userData= (object) $userData;
      $first_name =  $userData['first_name'];
      echo $first_name;
    var_dump($first_name);

     echo "</li>";
     
     }
     
     echo "</ul>"   ?>
 </div>
   </div>    
`code`

Comment: change $userData['first_name'] to $userData->first_name as you said before you wanted to use -> in the array that means you have to turn it to object and $userData = (object) $userData; do that for you but you still use an array if you want array you will need to delete the $userData=(object) $userData; line

Comment: Thanks. 

I think the problem is the first 3 objects returned are actually empty, could this be creating the error ?

`object(stdClass)#153 (0) { }`
`object(stdClass)#153 (0) { }`
`object(stdClass)#153 (0) { }`
`object(stdClass)#643 (24) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["facebook_id"]=> string(17) "10152805813948795" ["first_name"]=> string(3) "Nat" ["last_name"]=> string(10) "Palakawong" .... }`

Answer (score 0):

Please use type casting.

```
$userinfo = (array)$userInfo;
```

Then you access your key first_name.

```
echo $userinfo['first_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of use a different method to dump data ..

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($your_array);
exit;
```

It just simply bodes for a better presentation to see what is an object and what is an array.

You **cannot** access array members with the object notation. You can however cast your array as an object.

```
(object)$yourarray;
```

If you want to access array members, use :

```
$yourarray['first_name'];
```

If you cast as an object:

`$obj = (object)$yourarray`;

Now access:

```
$obj->firstname;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I got it eventually. The problem is some of the objects returned are empty. returns "stdClass Object()".
My question is how can I find if an object is empty first? If I pull from an empty object it throws an error.

Comment: Try to work with "isset" to see if the object exists. After that you could use "property_exists" .. http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php to probe for that particular property ..